# How to access session from a custom RouteBase in MVC5?

Tags: session, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, session-variables

I am trying to implement the ability to relatively transparently encrypt ids in ASP.NET MVC5. I have a series of custom HTML helpers that emit encrypted ids, e.g:
http://url/CityDetails/Edit/Vb7B_slYoRdt1cQD5mNum

The html helper stores the key in session scope.

Then, I have a class that implements System.Web.Routing.RouteBase, and the method GetRouteData is supposed to replace the encrypted id with the decrypted id. This works if I hard code the key, but if I store the key in session scope, and try to access it, Session is always null.

```
public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext){
     //Session is always null
     HttpSessionState session1 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session;
     ...
     return routeData;
}
```

Is there a way to get to the Session? I am clearly not understanding something about the life cycle here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, **you can't**.

In MVC, `HttpContext.Session` is not yet available during routing - it is too early in the application's lifecycle.

The first point where session state is available in MVC is during the Controller Creation stage.

[image: MVC 5 Application Lifecycle]

See [this MSDN article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application) for more information about the MVC lifecycle.

If you line that up with the [ASP.NET on IIS 7 Lifecycle documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252(v=vs.100).aspx) you can see that the routing handler gets called at the `PostResolveRequestCache` event. Session state is first populated at the `AcquireRequestState` event, and then the controller is instantiated and action executed in the `BeginProcessRequest` event.

1. Validate the request, which examines the information sent by the browser and determines whether it contains potentially malicious markup. For more information, see ValidateRequest and Script Exploits Overview.
2. Perform URL mapping, if any URLs have been configured in the UrlMappingsSection section of the Web.config file.
3. Raise the BeginRequest event.
4. Raise the AuthenticateRequest event.
5. Raise the PostAuthenticateRequest event.
6. Raise the AuthorizeRequest event.
7. Raise the PostAuthorizeRequest event.
8. Raise the ResolveRequestCache event.
9. **Raise the PostResolveRequestCache event. (Routing Executed)**
10. Raise the MapRequestHandler event. An appropriate handler is selected based on the file-name extension of the requested resource. The handler can be a native-code module such as the IIS 7.0 StaticFileModule or a managed-code module such as the PageHandlerFactory class (which handles .aspx files).
11. Raise the PostMapRequestHandler event.
12. **Raise the AcquireRequestState event. (Session State Acquired)**
13. Raise the PostAcquireRequestState event.
14. Raise the PreRequestHandlerExecute event.
15. **Call the ProcessRequest method (or the asynchronous version IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest) of the appropriate IHttpHandler class for the request. For example, if the request is for a page, the current page instance handles the request. (Controller Creation)**
16. Raise the PostRequestHandlerExecute event.
17. Raise the ReleaseRequestState event.
18. Raise the PostReleaseRequestState event.
19. Perform response filtering if the Filter property is defined.
20. Raise the UpdateRequestCache event.
21. Raise the PostUpdateRequestCache event.
22. Raise the LogRequest event.
23. Raise the PostLogRequest event.
24. Raise the EndRequest event.
25. Raise the PreSendRequestHeaders event.
26. Raise the PreSendRequestContent event.

Do note that it is [generally not considered a good practice to use Session state with ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220980/is-it-a-good-practice-to-avoid-using-session-state-in-asp-net-mvc-if-yes-why-a).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I guess the point I was trying to make is that regardless of how I access it - either via the httpContext.Session or the static way, session is always null.